# How to escape $ in m4 macro definition's name?

Tags: m4

I tried the following code

```
define(`$TITLE', `my title')
This is my $TITLE.
```

but the text remains unchanged when I call it with `m4`.

It seems that is `$` problem. Should I escape it?

EDIT:

I found that

```
define(`$TITLE', `my title')
This is my indir(`$TITLE')
```

work, but there is a better way to do it?

Also, such macro name is [referred](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Define) as **non-standard**, where could I find a list of such name?

> *GNU M4 1.4.18 manual, section 5.1 Defining a macro*
>
> As a GNU extension, the first argument to define does not have to be a simple word. It can be any text string, even the empty string. A macro with a **non-standard** name cannot be invoked in the normal way, as the name is not recognized. It can only be referenced by the builtins indir (see Indir) and defn (see Defn).

Comment: Normal use of m4 doesnot allow arbitrary names. You should start with insisting that you want to use gnu extensions. I can't see a question here, merely an unreasonable complaint, that you must use indir for arbitrary names. Unreasonable, because how could gnu define this otherwise.

Comment: Query sign because this is is not a rethorical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html) is *the* standard. It writes:

> Macro names shall consist of letters, digits, and underscores, where
>   the first character is not a digit. Tokens not of this form shall not
>   be treated as macros.

I think use of `defn` would better (instead of `indir`) because the POSIX standard doesn't contain `indir` (`defn` yes) and `defn` must work on other `m4`-implementation (not only GNU).

I think would better in your case if your variables would begin with underscore (not dollar sign): `_TITLE`. It's valid macro name and maybe doesn't appear in your text :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will prefix my macros by `_`.